# search for string in msg python

Tags: python, imaplib

I can print each email. What I want to do though is search each email for a string and return true of false if it has the string. How can I parase `msg` to do this?

```
conn.select(readonly=1) # Select inbox or default namespace
(retcode, messages) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
if retcode == 'OK':
    for num in messages[0].split(' '):
        print 'Processing :', messages
        typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(RFC822)')
        msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
        typ, data = conn.store(num,'-FLAGS','\\Seen')
        if retcode == 'OK':
            print data,'\n',30*'-'
            for line in msg:
                if "Subject: Thanks for your Walmart.com Order" in line:
                    print line

conn.close()
```

Comment: We now back to using `imaplib` instead of `IMAPClient` then?

Comment: Wrapping my head around both. `imaplib` keeps working but `IMAPClient` looks easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've got an email object `msg`, then you can do:

```
message_lines = msg.get_payload().splitlines()
```

Then loop over each line:

```
for line in message_lines:
    if 'Walmart' in line:
        pass # do whatever
```

But again, be careful of what the payload is...

The other option, is to have the IMAP server do the work:

```
(retcode, messages) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN) (TEXT walmart)')
```

This will subset the number of messages that need to be fetched and *then* you can apply more complex matching if required...

What's also possible is to search by subject (if that's ultimately what you want to do):

```
(retcode, messages) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN) (SUBJECT Thanks for your Walmart.com Order)')
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. I've gone back to using `IMAPClient` for now but what I just learned from your answer helped me there. Thank you.